# Split words with commas and replace character instead of null in bash

Tags: linux, bash, null, split

Hi I want to split word with commas and replace 0 character instead of null in bash.

For example; `hello,world,,abc,234,,41,1`

It could be =>

```
hello  
world   
0  
abc  
234  
0  
41  
1
```

How can I do this? Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk

```
s='hello,world,,abc,234,,41,1'
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i?$i:0}' <<< "$s"
hello
world
0
abc
234
0
41
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i'm here with example of pure bash 4 :)

```
#!/bin/bash

s='hello,world,,abc,234,,41,1'
IFS=","
for i in $s; do
 if [ -z $i ]; then echo 0; else echo $i; fi
done
```

output:

```
/usr/tmp $ ./1
hello
world
0
abc
234
0
41
1
```